# C++: Why would you extend and parameterize with the same class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

What is a good reason to do this?

```
template <class BaseClass>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
}
```

I'm looking at a colleague's code and I see this pattern, which I find to be very strange.

The only reason I can think of is that perhaps in DerivedClass, you want to construct a bunch of BaseClass instances. When you write the code, you don't know what the BaseClass could be, so you'd need to parameterize with it.

But, I don't see him doing that.

So why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: There is nothing really different here from regular inheritance. Why would you derive from a base type?

Comment: Its useful for mixins. Derived2<Derived1<Base>> v; would be chaining several classes.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I don't think that is the case. CRTP is more like: `class X : public CRTP<X> { … }`, which basically rules out of the possibility of `CRTP` inheriting itself from `X` or otherwise `X` would be a base of itself and the world would implode

Comment: @CaptainObvlious No, CRTP is `template< typename derived > class Base {};`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Correct. Was having a Glee moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is useful if `DerivedClass` is an interface adaptor which can extend any of a variety of `BaseClass`es.

It's similar to CRTP, where the base is parameterized on the derived class. However in this pattern the base isn't parameterized on anything, so it's not a template, so template bloat is avoided.

In CRTP, the base is abstract in a template-y sense (but not polymorphic). It specifies an interface with only partial implementation, and `static_cast`s itself to the derived type, thus covering similar conceptual ground as `virtual` functions in a real abstract class.

In this pattern, you have a concrete base class and a concrete derived class. Nothing is as abstract, so the concepts are a bit cleaner.

Comment: Patatoswatter is right on, in fact text-book correct.  I think a concrete example would help.